# Dual boot from two separate physical storage devices

Tags: operating-systems

I have a new laptop that has a 256GB NVMe SSD drive with Windows 10 currently installed. The laptop has 2 NVMe SSD slots, so I plan to move the 256GB SSD to the second slot, and insert a new 1TB SSD drive into the first slot.

Summary:

- Slot 1: 1TB SSD with Linux
- Slot 2: 256GB SSD with Windows

I plan to dual boot. Is there anything special I need to be aware of in order to make this possible? Can I simply move the first SSD into the second slot, install Linux on the new 1TB SSD, configure the Grub2 boot loader and go? Is there anything I'm missing?

As I type this out I'm feeling like it's a dumb question. I've done plenty of dual-booting in the past but I believe it was on separate partitions and not often on separate drives -- or at least it's been a while since I've done this. :D

Comment: This has nothing to do with computer _science_.

Comment: Yes it should work, let us  know if you run into any issues along the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just install the 2 separate operating systems on 2 separate drives, then choose which one you want to boot from using boot menu in BIOS. (often F11, or something similar, but depends on the manufacturer)

This is actually even easier then having 2 OS on 1 drive, so you should not encounter any issues.

You may want to unmount the other drive from each operating system though to prevent yourself from writing to those drives. (unmount linux drive from windows, and vice versa)

Comment: It was easier than doing it on the same drive. I guess I was worried about MBRs but I didn't run into any such issues.